# change className to using template literals

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styles

i'm trying to learn template literals, i have project of mine i need to use template literals there, i have a question which seems very simple, but dont know what i am doing wrong

this is working:

```
const classes = props.classes;

return (
<List
  component="div"
  data-testid="SelectionListt"

  className={classes.selectionList__sites}
>

</List>
);
```

my question is how should i turn that className using template literals.

This is what i have done:

```js
 const classes = props.classes;

  return (
    <List
      component="div"
      data-testid="SelectionListt"
       className={` ${classes + ".selectionList__sites"} `}`
     
    >
    
    </List>
  );
```

this is my selectionList__sites:

```js
 selectionList__sites: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: " red",
        color: "black",
        border: "1px solid yellow",
      },
    },
```

English is not my mother language so there could be mistakes.

Comment: any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Template literals have no need for regular quotes inside them, basically the entire content between backticks is handled as a string, except for values inside ${}.

Assuming that props.classes is a string, I would write your className like this:

```
className={`${classes}.selectionList__sites`}
```